# How to Export sqlite3 database as csv in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Can anyone tell me what goes in the `()` of this function?

I am trying to add an EXPORT button to EXPORT the sqlite3 database to a CSV file. I have added this function with all the rest of the functions:

```
def write_to_csv():

    with open('My Enable Info', 'a') as f:

        w=csv.writer(f,dialect='excel')

        w.writenow()
```

And then I added the button 7

```
b7=Button(window,text="Export",width=15,font='Helvetica', command=lambda:write_to_csv())

b7.grid(row=11,column=9)

b7.configure(background="yellow")
```

What must I put in the () ??

Thanks

Comment: ***"What must I put in the () ??"***: Nothing

Comment: where did you found method `writenow()` ? There is `writerow([1,2,3])` to write single row or `writerows([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ])` to write many rows at once. Read [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)

Comment: BTW: you can use `command=write_to_csv` - without `()` and without `lambda`

Comment: Thank you. That helps. I am new to Python and am teaching myself. So I am a little confused, when I use 1,2,3 or 1,2,3 4,5,6 - as you have shown, the cvs doc which is generated has "1,2,3" instead of the data in the database. I am sure I am missing something. Should 1 = name of column 1?